# Installing WordPress inside public/blog on Laravel 7 framework

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, nginx, laravel-7

I am trying to install the WordPress blog on my Laravel 7 app inside the public/blog directory, so that the blog is accessible via `example.com/blog` URL.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP7.4 and NGINX using Laravel Forge.

Here is what I have in my `nginx.conf`:

```
location /blog/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
    }
    
    location @wordpress {
        rewrite /blog/ /blog/index.php;
    }
    
    location ^/blog/index.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php?$query_string;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

The problem that I am having is when I try to access the blog, for the first time to run an install of WordPress, I am being redirected to the following URL `https://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/install` but then I have a file not found exception because the framework is trying to look for `install.php` in the `/home/forge/www.example.com/storage/app/protected/files/blog/wp-admin/install`, which clearly is not there.

The question is why this is happening and why the framework does this even after setting the NGINX and php7.4-fpm to the correct location of the blog?

I have tried switching all of my client routes off to test it, but so far nothing.

Comment: Why such a complicated solution? Why not use `blog.example.com` and redirect `www.example.com/blog` to that domain? I would absolutely recommend not to install a wordpress instance inside of your public folder.

Comment: @dbf inclining towards this solution, the only problem is that the site that I am moving had this particular URL structure, so I was trying to avoid having to redirect over 15000 urls to `blog.example.com`

Comment: Maybe you can create an alias for the blog that way you didn't have to rewrite url and you can move wordpress folder outside laravel

Comment: @Skyro682, not sure how to implement this? I have never done this, could you please expand?

Comment: @AlexB I'v never do it with nginx but i've find this : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-add-a-wordpress-install-to-blog-on-my-server-when-serves-a-different-app-via-nginx

Comment: @Skyro682, thanks, this solution works so far, I am going to test it all and see if all the rest of the WordPress works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, big thank you, Skyro682, for recommending the solution.

Here is what you need to do if you are in the same situation as I was.

Add the following above your regular location block `nginx.conf`:

```
    location ^/blog {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
    
#This is is your regular location for Laravel 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Restart your NGINX and PHP7.4 from the Laravel Forge panel or the terminal.

You should not be able to see the installation screen for your WordPress.

This approach works just fine with SEO friendly URLs